# RPM: replace a file with a generated one while upgrading

Tags: linux, rpm

Normally, this should not require a special action at all: a new file is generated in `%pre` or `%post`, and the old one is removed by the RPM mechanism while cleaning up the old content of the RPM being upgraded. The first complication: the auto generated file should keep the same name as the previous file (nothing to do with this: the old RPMs are scattered across multiple customers; and the technical specifications require to keep the name). If it is simply generated but does not exist in `%files`, the cleanup mechanism removes the generated file. Well, it is possible to keep a stub in `%files` to prevent the removing. But there is a second complication too: the generated file may have the same name as the previous file but equally may not (it depends on the environment now). Is there a way to manage the situation in an elegant way?

My current solution is pretty ugly: I do keep a stub file in `%files`. I generate the new file in `%post` and remove the old file in the same script if the name should be changed. Upon uninstall in `%preun`, I create the removed file again if I removed it in `%post` due to the name change. I do this to avoid an ugly RPM warning about deletion attempt of a non-existing file (since it is still listed in `%files`).

A lot of unnecessary and unnatural work. Say, if there was an option to dynamically instruct RPM (in `%post`) to keep a file instead of removing (because not in `%files` any more) while upgrading, it would make the situation dramatically simpler and clearer. Regretfully, I have not found any option similar to this. I would truly appreciate an advice to handle the situation in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create that file in %posttrans section.

See chapters "Scriptlets ordering" and "Saving state between scriptlets" at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:ScriptletSnippets#Scriptlet_Ordering

Comment: Well, thanks for the suggestion. This works indeed, and I think I go this way unless a better option is offered. I find this kind of resolution a bit unnatural since it suggests moving of the work to do into another location/time instead of correcting the undesired behavior (file removal). Anyway, the resolution looks much simpler and clearer than what I did "naturally" before. My additional complication relates to use of maven; it offers posttransScriptlet but loses %posttrans keyword while generating the spec file. I had to add line %posttrans as the first line of the scriptlet itself.